# fmax and fmin expected an identifier Visual Studio c++

Tags: c++, identifier

```
void SplitColors(unsigned char *rgb, int count, unsigned char *r, unsigned char *g, unsigned char *b, unsigned char *y, unsigned char *cb, unsigned char *cr, bool useRGBA)
{
    int multiplier = useRGBA ? 4 : 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (y || cb || cr)
        {
            int yy, ccb, ccr;
            RGB_to_YCbCr(
                rgb[i * multiplier + 0],
                rgb[i * multiplier + 1],
                rgb[i * multiplier + 2],
                yy, ccb, ccr);
            yy = fmax(0, yy);  yy = fmin(255, yy);
            ccb = fmax(0, ccb); ccb = fmin(255, ccb);
            ccr = fmax(0, ccr); ccr = fmin(255, ccr);
            if (y != NULL)
                y[i] = (unsigned char)yy;
            if (cb != NULL)
                cb[i] = (unsigned char)ccb;
            if (cr != NULL)
                cr[i] = (unsigned char)ccr;
        }
        if (r != NULL)
            r[i] = rgb[i * multiplier + 0];
        if (g != NULL)
            g[i] = rgb[i * multiplier + 1];
        if (b != NULL)
            b[i] = rgb[i * multiplier + 2];
    }
}
```

Don't understand why the fmax and fmin functions aren't working in this one? I've declared the yy etc as int? Also doesn't work if I try to declare them as double...

Comment: I'm using <math.h> fyi

Comment: why do you `#include <math.h>`? It's c++, `#include <cmath>`

Answer (score 0):

`fmin` and `fmax` were introduced to C++ as part of the C++11 iteration, I don't think Visual C++ supports them yet, at least up to VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

`fmax` and `fmin` are C++11, but you could simply use [`max`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) and [`min`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/) since you're using them on `int`s anyway.

Also, since you're using the two functions to clamp your integers to the 0..255 range, you could define a function just for that:

```
int clamp(int val, int min = 0, int max = 255)
{
    return std::min(std::max(val, min), max);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
yy = clamp(yy);
```